# Knockout Unable to parse bindings only when running app on Heroku

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

The issue is that when i run the web app in my development environment (Windows 7 64-bit) the knockout bindings work as designed, but when the app is run on Heroku the same exact page with the same exact data gives me a

Uncaught Error: Unable to parse bindings
Message: ReferenceError: searchLink is not defined;
Bindings value: attr:{href:searchLink}

I am using the knockout mapper to parse json into the needed objects, the ViewModels are

```
var CoachesViewModel = function(data){  
    var self = this;
    ko.mapping.fromJS(data, mapping, this);                
}
var PendingCoachModel = function(data){
    var self = this;
    ko.mapping.fromJS(data, mapping, this),
}
var mapping = {
 'coaches': {
     create: function(options) {
        return new CoachesViewModel(options.data);
        }
    },
'pendingCoaches':{
    create:function(options){
        return new PendingCoachModel(options.data);
        }
     }
}   
var viewModel = function(coaches,pendingCoaches){
    var self = this;
    ko.mapping.fromJS(coaches, mapping, this);
    ko.mapping.fromJS(pendingCoaches, mapping, this);
}                           
var vm = new viewModel(${team.serializedCoaches()},${team.serializedPendingCoaches()});
            ko.applyBindings(vm);



The json is 
{'coaches':[{'email':'noemail502e6c13e4b0831b62e6896e@...','name':'Jim    Smith','searchImgLink':'http://localhost:9000/...','searchLink':'http://localhost:9000...','userId':'502e6c4b...96e'}]}
'pendingCoaches':[{'notifyId':'512bd9b874062909605d1','user':{'email':'hdog_lbf50f9698ae4ol.com','name':'Bob Johnson(Obf.)','pendingUser':false,'searchImgLink':'http://localhost:9000..','searchLink':'http://localhost:9000...','userId':'502e6c41e4e691e2'}}]


<!-- ko foreach: coaches -->    
    <div class = 'tCoach'>
       //this is where it breaks
        <a data-bind="attr:{href:searchLink}"><img data-bind = "attr:{src:searchImgLink}" class = 'coachImage'/></a>
        <div class = 'coachInfo'>
            <p><a data-bind="attr:{href:searchLink},text:name" class = 'coachName'></a></p> 
            <p data-bind = "text:reducedEmail"></p> 
            <p data-bind="if:isHeadCoach">Head Coach</p>    
        </div>          
        <img data-bind="bindCoachDropdown:self,attr:{manId:userId}" class = 'hd_drop managers'  src = '/public/images/dropdown_orange.png' />
    </div>      
<!-- /ko -->
```

I removed functions that and variables that were not relevant to the question..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem. Realized that our HTML minify module removed html tags and therefor breaking knockout